# Why does appear "passing 'const Person' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers" while using STL copy algorithm?

Tags: c++, stl, copy, istream-iterator

I'm trying to implement a max heap on user defined structures, and I use the `std::copy_n()` algorithm to take input from `heap.in` file, but I receive this kind of error from the compiler:

> passing 'const Person' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers

Can anyone tell me where the issue is?

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


std::ifstream fin ("heap.in");
std::ofstream fout ("heap.out");

struct Person {
    int age;
    std::string name;

    bool operator < (const Person p) const{
        if (this->age != p.age)
            return this->age < p.age;
        return this->name < p.name;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& flux, Person& p) {
        flux >> p.name >> p.age;
        return flux;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& flux, Person p) {
        flux << "(" << p.name << ", " << p.age << "); ";
        return flux;
    }

    friend std::ifstream& operator >> (std::ifstream& flux, Person& p) {
        flux >> p.name >> p.age;
        return flux;
    }

    friend std::ofstream& operator << (std::ofstream& flux, Person p) {
        flux << "(" << p.name << ", " << p.age << "); ";
        return flux;
    }
};

int n;
std::vector <Person> Heap;

int main () {
    fin >> n; 
    std::copy_n (Heap.begin (), n, std::istream_iterator <Person> (fin));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you copy something to an input stream? You copy to an output stream, you copy from an input stream.

Comment: @Sami Bărbuț-Dică What is the difference between the operator < and the operator <=?

Comment: Where in the code do you get the error? Can you please mark the line!?

Comment: Why are you adding more and more code? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I found the error. It was the wrong order of the arguments in copy algorithm:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you meant this

```
int main () {
    fin >> n;
    std::copy_n (std::istream_iterator <Person> (fin), n, std::back_inserter(Heap));
    return 0;
}
```

`std::copy_n` copies n items from it's first argument to it's third. If you want to append to a vector then you must use the wrapper `std::back_inserter` as `std::copy_n` won't increase the size of the vector by itself.

Comment: The code has got a lot more complex since I posted this answer. The earlier version was similar to the above.

Comment: Thank you, @john! That was the problem. I was mistaken the order of arguments.

Comment: The new code is the complete one. I mean the whole bunch of methods for a max heap implemented as an array. Thanks again!

Comment: @SamiBărbuț-Dică It's actually better to post the minimal example. Had you posted the full code originally I probably wouldn't have answered as there's too much code to read through.

Comment: @jonh, thanks for the advice! I'm a beginner in using StackOverflow for posting questions. I'll bear that in my mind!